# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference

Tags: nullpointerexception

Help me fix this error

Here's my logcat

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object
>   reference
>   --->membersList.addAll (member);

I tried to initialize and tried several times but it was no use. Please help me solve this problem.

```
10-14 16:11:09.995 31885-31885/com.designzoos.indj E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.
                                                                        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:111)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
                                                                        at com.designzoos.indj.presentation.view.adapter.ChooseArtistAdapter.<init>(ChooseArtistAdapter.java:72)
                                                                        at com.designzoos.indj.presentation.view.activity.ChooseArtistActivity.showMembersData(ChooseArtistActivity.java:155)
                                                                        at com.designzoos.indj.presentation.presenter.PostArtistPresenter$MembersLikeDataObserver.onNext(PostArtistPresenter.java:75)
                                                                        at com.designzoos.indj.presentation.presenter.PostArtistPresenter$MembersLikeDataObserver.onNext(PostArtistPresenter.java:54)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:198)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:250)
                                                                        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Here is my adapter
(ChooseArtistAdapter.java:72) --->membersList.addAll(member);

```
public class ChooseArtistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChooseArtistAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable,SearchView {
private ArrayList<Members>member = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Members>membersList;
private RecordFilter filter;
Context mContext;
@Inject
PostArtistPresenter postArtistPresenter;

public ChooseArtistAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Members> member) {

//        if(member==null)return;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.membersList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.member = member;
    **membersList.addAll(member);**

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_artist_adapter, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( final ViewHolder holder,  int position) {
    final Members members = membersList.get(position);
    holder.artistName.setText(members.getName());
//        if(){
//            holder.artistName.setText(members.getName());
//        }else if(){
//            holder.artistName.setText(members.getGroup()+" 
 "+members.getName());
//        }
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(members.getImageUrl()).listener(new 
 RequestListener<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            holder.imageViewPlaceHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    })
            .into(holder.artist_image_cover);

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        boolean isSelectClick=true;
        int count =0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Context context = view.getContext();

            if(isSelectClick==true){
                holder.selectImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isSelectClick=false;
                count=1;
                //post
                    ((ChooseArtistActivity) context).postPresenter();


            }else if(isSelectClick==false){
                holder.selectImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isSelectClick=true;
                count=-1;
                //delete
                    ((ChooseArtistActivity) context).deletePresenter();


            }
            ((ChooseArtistActivity)context).setCountText(count);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (null == membersList)
    {
        return 0;
    }else{
        return membersList.size();
    }
}




public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.imageViewPlaceHolder)
    CircularImageView imageViewPlaceHolder;

    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.artist_image_cover)
    CircularImageView artist_image_cover;

    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.selectImage)
    public
    CircularImageView selectImage;

    @BindView(R.id.artistName)
    TextView artistName;

    @Nullable
    @BindView(R.id.check)
    public TextView check;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private ChooseArtistActivity chooseArtistActivity;



    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        //onClick
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just read the stack trace of the exception. The `member` argument passed to the constructor of your class is null. You can't add all elements of `null` to a list. That doesn't make sense. So, if null is a valid value for this argument, then check that it's not null before trying to add all its elements. If it's not a valid value, then fix the code that calls that constructor so that it never calls that constructor with null.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the constructor does not have a null value. Please look below        D/adapter   [ 10-14 18:01:14.988 14449:14449 D/[com.designzoos.indj.data.entity.Members@76b7f2d, com.designzoos.indj.data.entity.Members@35members

Comment: It does, othewise you wouldn't get this exception.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
if(member != null)
    membersList.addAll(member);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was not solved. It seems that you can not import data. Could you give me another solution?